# What's the use of HTML Input element that has no value?

Tags: html, forms, input

Just wondering, why to use an input element with out a value attribute.

is it for some security reasons ?
is it included in form submission ?
and if so, what value would it have?

EX:

```
<input type="hidden" id="X" name="x">
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The default value it is empty string, it's no difference with `value=""`.

Comment: so it will be included in form submission?

Comment: As long as it has 'name' attribute.

Comment: even if dont have name attribute will be submit it I think so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will show up in the request as an empty variable. You can use this to check whether it is set or not.

Comment: you mean it will be included in form submission as (&x=&...) ?

Comment: If the action is set to `GET`, yes.

Comment: and if POST, it won't be included?

Comment: It will, just not part of URL.

Comment: okay thanks a lot, any idea what's the use of such a thing? security reason? for ex anti spam?

Comment: Because sometimes helps knowing if the value is present or if it is present but it has no value. For example you could apply a security check/verification only if a certain key exists (checksum?) or delete a certain value if the key exists but is is empty. And most of the times `""` is a value too.